# Strptime fails when working with a dataframe

Tags: r, posix, strptime

Strptime seems to be missing something in this scenario:

```
aDateInPOSIXct <- strptime("2018-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
someText <- "asdf"
df <- data.frame(aDateInPOSIXct, someText, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
bDateInPOSIXct <- strptime("2019-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df[1,1] <- bDateInPOSIXct
```

Assignment of bDate to the dataframe fails with:

> Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

And a warning:

> provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables

I want to use both POSIXct dates and POSIXct date-times to compare this and that. It's way less work than manipulating character strings -- and POSIX takes care of the time zone issues. Unfortunately, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to cast your calls to `strptime` to `POSIXct` explicitly:

```
aDateInPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2018-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
someText <- "asdf"
df <- data.frame(aDateInPOSIXct, someText, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
bDateInPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2019-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

df[1,1] <- bDateInPOSIXct
```

Check the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) which says:

> Character input is first converted to class "POSIXlt" by strptime: numeric input is first converted to "POSIXct".

Comment: For heaven's sake! I was relying on the documentation for strptime, which says, 'strptime turns character representations into an object of class "POSIXlt".' I didn't know that a conversion required piggybacking two functions.  Many thanks to you, Tim.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. There was no visible difference in str(df), so this is knowledge that will serve me well.